# What is the easiest way to use material design in a react-native iOS app?

Tags: material-design, react-native, material-ui

I have found these partial implementations on Github as the leading contenders although they have a way to go:

- [react-native-material-kit](https://github.com/xinthink/react-native-material-kit)
- [react-native-material-design](https://github.com/react-native-material-design/react-native-material-design)

They are lacking some components at this time that I would like to utilize. Is there an alternative solution that I'm missing?

Comment: newcomers : react-native-material-design is no longer maintained

Comment: can't we use material-ui along with react native somehow??

Answer (score 20):

We recently released React Native Paper at Callstack: https://reactnativepaper.com/

Some highlights include:

- Follows latest material design guidelines
- Nice theming API which allows you to switch themes dynamically
- Accessible by default
- Supports RTL mode
- Works on both Android and iOS, including Expo

There is also official integration for React Navigation for our Bottom Navigation component.

Here are some screenshots:

[image: Button][image: TextInput][image: FAB]

Not sure what components you're missing. So not sure if this satisfies your needs.

Answer (score 16):

I'm working on [react-native-material-ui](https://github.com/xotahal/react-native-material-ui) which should be close to [material-ui](http://www.material-ui.com/#/).

We needed to have option to completely and very easily change style/theme of the application. And there is no library that provides that possibility. Of course, you can set couple of things via props of component. But you have to change it on every place in your code where you use that component.

In [react-native-material-ui](https://github.com/xotahal/react-native-material-ui)

- you can define object that will be merged with default styles and use everywhere in your app - very easy
- there is still possibility to change style of only one component via props
- or you can use your style even in your own components (via context)

Comment: Please you must say that your are the maintainer of the solution your explain here :p

Answer (score 8):

I believe this library by [xinthink](https://github.com/xinthink/react-native-material-kit) will achieve what you're after.

I'm using it both on Android and iOS.

To be honest though, all those libraries JUST give you some styles, that you could also write yourself.

For example you could create a material design card like so:

```
       <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
          <View style={styles.cardContainer}>
            <View style={styles.card}>
              <View resizeMode="cover" style={styles.cardTitleContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.cardTitle}>Commented on</Text>
              </View>
              <View  // TextView padding not handled well on Android https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3233
                style={{
                  padding : 15,
                }}
                >
                <Text style={styles.cardContent}>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                  Mauris sagittis pellentesque lacus eleifend lacinia...
                </Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.cardAction}>
                <Text>My Action</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
```

using the following styles:

```
  cardContainer:{
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    padding: 20,
    marginTop: self.props.device.platform === 'android' ? 56 : 0,
  },

  card:{
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    borderRadius: 2,
    borderColor: '#ffffff',
    borderWidth: 1,
    shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)',
    shadowOpacity: 0.8,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    shadowOffset: {
      height: 1,
      width: 2,
    },
  },
  cardTitleContainer:{
    flex: 1,
    height: 170,
  },
  cardTitle:{
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 120,
    left: 26,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    padding: 16,
    fontSize: 24,
    color: '#000000',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },

  cardContent:{
    padding:0,
    color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54)',
  },

  cardAction:{
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderTopColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    padding: 15,
  },
```

I got this example code from the library I shared in my link. You will also notice  there are no custom components in this library either, just styles.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using react-native-material-ui and combine it with a Redux store.
This way I can have theme-switching on the fly!

Unfortunately initially we have to define styles per control, since the 'ThemeProviders uiTheme connector' of react-native-material-ui seems to be a one way ticket.

Anyways, if everything is wired up, I can manage all my styles in one big styles.js  ,consisting only one Platform.OS query, multiple skins and change complete themes via a drop down causing actions/state changes, ready to save in a local persistent storage.

react-native-material-ui looks very cool.

```
<ActionButton
              actions={[
                  { icon: 'email', label: 'Email' },
                  { icon: 'phone', label: 'Phone' },
                  { icon: 'sms', label: 'Text' },
                  { icon: 'favorite', label: 'Favorite' },
              ]}
              //not defined
              //hidden={this.state.bottomHidden}
              icon="share"
              transition="speedDial"
              onPress={(action) => {
                  if (myPlatform === 'android') {
                      ToastAndroid.show(action, ToastAndroid.SHORT);
                  }
              } }
              style={{
                  positionContainer: { bottom: 76 },
                  container: myStyle.testBack, //<--DYNAMIC !
              }}
              />
```